# how to increment a number in vim

Tags: vim

I found a really neat way of incrementing a number in text in vim. It works perfectly fine but only if I yank one line. If there is a whole paragraph in which I want to increment one number it does not work.
Here is how it works on single line:

```
qa
Y
p
Ctrl-A
q
```

and then type 15@a to perform the macro 15 times.

Does anyone know how to apply the same logic to something like this:

```
text 1
bla bla 1
```

So what I want is:

```
text 2
bla bla 2

text 3
bla bla 3

... and so on
```

Comment: Maybe add `j$` to move to the next line?

Comment: just mark the lines with `Ctrl+V` and then press Ctrl+A

Comment: `qayipjo<Esc>pvip<C-a>q` and then `15@a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to record the following macro:

```
qayipjo<Esc>pvip<C-a>q
```

Breakdown:

```
qa      start recording
yip     yank inner paragraph
jo<Esc> insert line after paragraph
p       paste
vip     select inner paragraph
<C-a>   increment all numbers
q       stop recording
```

This macro may be repeated via `15@a`.

Comment: ... it worked for the first time and now after I put 15@a I got only one copy of the paragraph pasted (instead of 15)? Would you know why?

Comment: Are your paragraphs only 2 lines long each? If they're longer, you should replace `j` with something like `}`

Answer (score 1):

Could you test this solution:

```
:g/./exec "normal \<C-a>"
```